# Custom Android preferences background

Tags: android, background, customization, preferenceactivity

I'm currently trying to set custom background for preference screen. I've created `PreferenceActivity`

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);
}
}
```

Here are my Preference layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    >
    <CheckBoxPreference 
        android:key="pref_Autoplay"
        android:title="@string/pref_Autoplay"
        android:summary="@string/pref_Autoplay_summ"
        android:defaultValue="false"/>
    <ListPreference 
        android:entryValues="@array/pref_Voice_values" 
        android:entries="@array/pref_Voice_entries" 
        android:key="pref_Voice" 
        android:summary="Choose male or female reader" 
        android:title="Readers voice" 
        android:defaultValue="female"/>


</PreferenceScreen>
```

As I read here to change background I need to create my own theme with style. Here it is:

```
<style name="PrefsTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/prefs_bg</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/prefs_bg</item>
        <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/listViewPrefs</item>
    </style>

    <style name="listViewPrefs" parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView">
        <item name="android:background">@color/prefs_bg</item>
        <item name="android:cacheColorHint">@color/prefs_bg</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/prefs_bg</item>
    </style>
```

All I need is to set some image background for preferences list. My image is `@drawable/prefs_bg`. When I set `windowBackground` to image and `background` to some color, preferences list background uses color instead of picture. But when I set background to `@drawable/prefs_bg` preferences list background appears with my picture and Radio Button dialog for my `ListPreference` item is also using image background.

Please help, how can I set image background for preferences list without affecting background of radio button dialog of some of the preferences item?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok. I've found how to solve my problem. It was my fault. To set Preference background only need

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/prefs_bg</item>
```

This one was unnecessary:

```
<item name="android:background">@color/prefs_bg</item>
<item name="android:cacheColorHint">@color/prefs_bg</item>
```

Answer (score 2):

To add dynamic nature, this will also work. Add this to the PreferenceActivity. We can set Background Color also in the same way.

```
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setupActionBar();
    setupSimplePreferencesScreen();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16)
        this.getListView().setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(...);
}
```